# Having trouble with a VBA For loop

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer

So this there is a JavaScript table generated on a web page that I'm trying to loop through and click the links. The links open a popup and then the VBA clicks a button in the pop up that updates and closes the window. It works perfectly for the first popup but when it hits the last line "Next link" it goes back up to the `For` but the variable for "link" is empty but there are 2 more links and it throws an error because link = empty.

I have made another simple loop that just cycles through links in `allLinks` to make sure it's seeing them and it does work so they are loaded.

I would be grateful for any help thanks for everyone's time.

Oh and the `Application.Wait`'s are temporary I will replace them with `Do While` when I get this guy running right.

It looks like link loses it's properties after the button click on
`wd.document.getElementById("btnAddItem").Click`

```
Set allLinks = appIE.document.getElementById("tblItems").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In allLinks
    appIE.Navigate link
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    For Each wd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If wd = "Internet Explorer" Then
            If InStr(UCase(wd.document.Title), "ITEM") <> 0 Then
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                wd.document.getElementById("btnAddItem").Click
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

                Exit For

            End If
        End If
    Next wd
Next link
```

I just had to Comment out the Exit For it was kicking out of both for loops

```
Set allLinks = appIE.document.getElementById("tblItems").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In allLinks
    appIE.Navigate link
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    For Each wd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If wd = "Internet Explorer" Then
            If InStr(UCase(wd.document.Title), "ITEM") <> 0 Then
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                wd.document.getElementById("btnAddItem").Click
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

                'Exit For

            End If
        End If
    Next wd
Next link
```

Comment: It's possible that `tbltems` gets re-drawn and your `allLinks` collection then points to nothing (since those original elements are now gone from the page).  You might need to refresh that collection each time through the link and use a counter to keep track of where you are in the table.

Comment: Store the URLs of `allLinks` in a collection or array *before* you start navigating them - iterate that collection of string URLs, it won't be tied to `appIE.document` anymore.

Comment: Can you please inform us, What changes occurred in the original window after the code clicks on popup and close the another window? How many links are in your web page and how many of them are empty? Can you please provide a sample HTML page that we can run with the above VBA code? It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: I can't share the site it's on our intranet. I'm going to work it later today. I think Tim is right and the table gets re-drawn so I lose all of my values. I'll try a counter and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @Emein, Is your issue solved? If yes, Can you please share the solution? If not, Can you inform us the current status for your issue. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: I did get it to work. The "Exit For" at the end of the If statement was kicking it all the way out so I was losing my allLinks I commented it out and it's fine now. I  but I have another issue with it on the last loop it wont do the last click.